# Android Paging Library, Endless RecyclerView, Retrofit

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, paging

I have an EditText and a RecyclerView. I want to observe the EditText and get Data from TMDB API to the endless RecyclerView. I can get Data from API to the endless Recyclerview with Retrofit and Paging library. But I can only send a query to the API from viewModel, I want to observe EditText and send that query to the API. How can I achieve this?
ViewModel:

```
class AddViewModel(private val movieRepository : MoviePagedListRepository) : ViewModel() {
    val isError = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val isLoading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
    val movieSeriesETContent = MutableLiveData<String>()
    
    val  moviePagedList : LiveData<PagedList<Movie>> by lazy {
        movieRepository.fetchLiveMoviePagedList("break",compositeDisposable)
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        compositeDisposable.dispose()
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
vm.movieSeriesETContent.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            Log.d("Murad",it)
        })

vm.moviePagedList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            adapter.submitList(it)
        })
```

You can see the request "break" in the ViewModel class, but I want to send a query when I observe the EditText where I've put Log.d("Murad",it) for now.

Comment: I have already implemented the above usecase in https://github.com/andor201995/WatchIt/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/andor/watchit/screens/searchmovie/controller/SearchMovieFragment.kt

u can give a look at it

Answer (score 0):

You should replace your `EditText` with `SearchView` and apply `OnQueryTextListener`. So that there will not be any requirement for observer on text change.

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            //you can show a progress bar here as well
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

            // here you can call your ViewModel's searchQueryMethod()
          
            return true;
        }
});
```

in your observer you simple need the change data set on your adapter. I did create an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=buzz.watcher) with TMDB API as well, and this is what I also did to get movies list.

Happy Coding !